# How do I push my local branch to remote at a specific commit?

Tags: git

I created a new branch off "main" to work on and made several local commits. I don't want my commits pushed, but I want to push this branch to remote origin (without my local commits) so that other people can see the branch. Any tips for doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just push main as the new remote branch. For example, let's say you created the "comments" branch locally, and committed some work. You based the branch on master, so you can simply push the master branch to origin under a new name:

```
git push origin main:comments
```

Don't forget to set up tracking between the origin branch and your local copy of comments:

```
git checkout comments
git branch --set-upstream-to origin comments
```